# Why is my UK visa delayed?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

I applied for a UK Standard Visitor visa for on 23rd August 2018 at the visa application centre in Mumbai. On the same day, I got an SMS saying *The visa application for [GWF reference number] was forwarded to UKVI on 8/23/2018.*

I have applied for non-settlement visa that is supposed to be processed within 15 working days. Four of my colleagues applied at the same time and were issed a visa on 8th Sep 2018.

Today I received this notice by email:

> NOTIFICATION LETTER TO ADVISE THAT APPLICATION MAY NOT BE PROCESSED WITHIN SERVICE STANDARDS
>
> Your Reference:   UKVI /  GWF
>
> 12/09/2018
>
> Dear 
>   Thank you for your UK visa application which has been received and is under consideration.  We aim to process applications:
>
> 1. Non-settlement within 15 working days
> 2. Priority Visas within 5 working days
> 3. Settlement within 60 working days.
>
> Unfortunately, we will not be able to make a decision on your visa application within these service standards because we require further information to fully assess your application. We will contact you should we require any additional information from you.
>
> Please be assured that we will continue to progress your application to enable a decision to be made as soon as possible. We will notify you by email once a decision has been made.
>
> Please do not go to the visa application centre until you have been advised that your passport is ready for collection.

Anybody got similar email? Did you get the visa? After how many days later you got the visa? Is it sign of refusal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UKVI have advised you that they won't meet their service target for your visa application because they need more information. That's all.

They haven't indicated what information they need, nor how much longer things will take. They have **not** refused your application (nor have they granted it, yet)

The fact that your colleagues have been granted their visas has no bearing on your application.

Someone else may have received the same email, but their experence has no bearing on your application, neither in time elapsed, nor in outcome.

The only thing you can do is wait.

Comment: Got my Visa yesterday :-) Happy