# UK Visa correspondance from immigration

Tags: visas, india, standard-visitor-visas, vfs-global

I am an applicant from India who is trying to apply for UK Visitor Visa on priority from VFS Global. My application was received successfully but I received this very distressing email from the Immigration office.

"Unfortunately, we will not be able to make a decision on your visa application within these service standards because we require further information to fully assess your application. We will contact you should we require any additional information from you.
"

Should I be worried here? I don't know what other information I can submit. I have submitted Bank Statements, Demat Holdings Statement, Recurring Deposit Summary, Leave Letter from the company, Tax returns for 3 years, Salary Slips, a Personal Covering Letter, Flight Tickets ,Hotel Bookings.

What can possibly be missing here? Or is this message something everyone is getting now due to delays caused in processing times due to the pandemic?

Comment: Related question with similar email body - https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/122240/why-is-my-uk-visa-delayed . As you paid for priority service they are just saying its not possible to make a decision in 5 days. Maybe they need to do some additional background checks or they are short staffed. Only UKVI can tell. Priority service is non refundable AFAIK and not a guarantee that your visa will be issued within 5 days.

Comment: As stated in section 9 of https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents/guide-to-supporting-documents-visiting-the-uk, the UK does not as a rule require evidence of travel bookings as part of the application process

Comment: UKVI is experiencing a lot of volumes these days. Be prepared for 1/2 weeks delay to the visa decision.

Answer (score 4):

As RedBaron says, all the message means is that they are not able to make a decision in the time allowed. You should be "worried" in the sense that you will not receive a decision in the Priority Service timeframe. This may impact your travel plans. It does mean your case is not straightforward, but it does not mean your application is going to be rejected.

"Needing more information" does not mean they need more information from you. You have been asked for nothing, so send nothing. They explicitly say they will ask if they need more information.

Do nothing until asked, but be prepared for a delay.